# Injecting modules in Angular at runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this Angular (1.3.15) code:

```
var my_app = angular.module('my_app', ["ui.bootstrap", "toastr"]);

my_app.module("template/foo/bar.html", []).run([$templateCache, function($templateCache) { /* ... global template ... */ }]);
```

which injects bootstrap and toastr libraries and creates a template that I use in all my other JS files.

Now, not all files need `ui.bootstrap`, but given the fact that I placed it in my `global.js` file (which is loaded with every page, no matter wat), Angular is complaining about missing libraries (`ui.bootstrap`).

My question is: can I inject `ui.bootstrap` only in the controllers I need it and leave my `gobal.js` like this:

```
var my_app = angular.module('my_app', ["toastr"]);
```

Also, this applies to quite some other libraries I'm currently loading in my global JS file, not only `ui.bootstrap`.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this is to split your code into multiple modules by some rule. This way only the modules that need `ui.bootstrap` will have it as a dependency, other won't.

If that's still not clean enough for you then you might want to take a look at [Browserify](http://browserify.org/)

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. I'm asking for a way to load modules dynamically because I genuinely need to do that, and not split my current code.